# smooth scrolling on anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a smooth scroll effect when i click a button in my navbar.
It jumps to the link but no smooth scroll effect

My section code:

```
<section id="home"></section>
```

And here is the button associated to it

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#home">home</a>
```

Here are some JS scripts that I tried but none of them worked

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Add smooth scrolling to all links
$("a").on('click', function(event) {

// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
if (this.hash !== "") {
  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
  });
} // End if
```

The second one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check for hash when page has loaded
    if (getHash() != null) {
        checkForScrolling();
    }
});

// listen for hash change event here
window.onhashchange = function() {
    checkForScrolling();
};

// return hash if so or null if hash is empty
function getHash() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    if (hash != '') {
        return hash;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

// this function handles your scrolling
function checkForScrolling() {
    // first get your element by attribute selector
    var elem = $('[data-anchor="' + getHash() + '"]');

    // cheeck if element exists
    if (elem.length > 0) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: elem.offset().top
        }, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you had a typo in the first method? It has no closing brackets to the click function https://jsfiddle.net/bjjf24c8/1/ I added the closing brackets. Also no closing brackets to document ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// Add smooth scrolling to all links
$("a").on('mouseover', function(event) {

// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
if (this.hash !== "") {
  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
  });
} // End if 
});
});
```

```css
body, html, .main {
    height: 100%;
}

section {
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


<section id="home">HOME
<br><a class="nav-link" href="#myAnchor">go2end</a>    

    </section>
<div class="main">    
<section style="background-color:blue"></secion>
</div>
<a id="myAnchor" class="nav-link" href="#home">home</a>
```

What is being scrolled is the page, so to best reference it you need this code when using jQuery:

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
```

The correction by **@bru02** is astute and so I use that code to demonstrate the smooth scrolling effect. However, I change the code so that a user need only mouseover the link instead of clicking it -- more comfortable for saving one's wrist.  And, provide HTML so that one may scroll up or down the page, too.

The script itself apparently originates from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll) and works there, too. The script as cited by the OP only failed because of an incomplete copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

Amusing this is not a request to debug your code, here is a [working example](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/dpBMVP)

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

and description is [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

Answer (score 2):

You forgott the closing brackets after the `}); } // End if` part.
So if you paste this  `}); });` to the first one's bottom it will work fine.

The finished code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Add smooth scrolling to all links
$("a").on('click', function(event) {

// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
if (this.hash !== "") {
  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
  });
} // End if 
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `attr()` to get the `id` value then set `scrollTop` value to the particular id `offset().top` and use `animate()` for smooth scroll on `click`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).on("click", ".nav-link", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var hash = $(this).attr("href");
  if ($(hash).length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  //console.log($(hash).offset().top)
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link" href="#home">home</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="#about">about</a>
<div class="other-section">
  other-section<br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
</div>
<section id="home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</section>
<div class="other-section">
  other-section<br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
  <br> other-section
</div>
```